# GCC gives confusing warning message when using pointer to struct <typedef>

Tags: gcc, gcc4

On compiling the following C program, GCC emits a warning message which is somewhat confusing.

**Program Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
} dummy_t;

void myfunc (dummy_t   *pointer)
{
    printf("x = %d\n", pointer->x);
}

int main ()
{
    dummy_t    d = { 10 };

    /* INCORRECT. */
    myfunc((struct dummy_t *)&d);

    /* Correct. */
    // myfunc((dummy_t *)&d);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation**

```
bash$ gcc c.c
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:17:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘myfunc’ from incompatible pointer type
 myfunc((struct dummy_t *)&d);
                ^
c.c:7:6: note: expected ‘struct dummy_t *’ but argument is of type ‘struct dummy_t *’
void myfunc (dummy_t   *pointer)
```

Notice how *both* the expected type and the argument type are reported to have the same value `struct dummy_t *`. This is confusing.

Shouldn't the expected type be `dummy_t *`?

The above program is a simplified version of the actual code where I faced this problem.

**GCC Version**

```
bash$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right that the error message is confusing. A newer version gives a much better error message:

```
note: expected 'dummy_t * {aka struct <anonymous> *}' but argument is 
of type 'struct dummy_t *'
```

As you can see, `dummy_t` and `struct dummy_t` are different types. With this declaration:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
} dummy_t;
```

You are typedef'ing an *anonymous struct*. However, later when you do `struct dummy_t`, you are *forward declaring* a new struct named `dummy_t`. Clearly, these are two different types, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide the newer version value.